# I'm working on an equation at Latex with \cases in \cases, but i didnt manage to make it work. The picture of the the wanted equation is below

Tags: equations, amsmath, cases

This is the code i tried. I changed some stuff, but still got a bunch of errors.

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}
 \usepackage{ucs}
 \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

 \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

 \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amstext}
 \begin{document}
\begin{equation}
f_{ij}(\hat{r}_{ij};\tilde{\Omega}_i ,\tilde{\Omega}_j )=
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if } \begin{cases}
\text{ } & ( \hat{e}_{\alpha} \cdot \hat{r}_{ij} \leq \text{cos(\delta)} \text{) for some patch \alpha on i} \\
\text{and} & \text{(} \hat{e}_{\beta} \cdot \hat{r}_{ji} \leq \text{cos(\delta)} \text{ for some patch \beta on j}
\end{cases} \\
0 & \text{otherwise} 
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The equation i try to build:

[image]

Thank you for any tipps! :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! Rather than giving code fragments it is better to post a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). Currently we have to guess what you're doing and it is difficult reconstruct, and hence fix, your problem from the information in your question. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you --- and much more likely that they will!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrote a lot of maths as text (parentheses, for instance, or cos, which is a math operator). I simplified your code, used the `cases*` environment, from `mathtools`, which has its second part automatically switched to text mode. Also, I found a `\widetilde` looked better over a `Ω`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  f_{ij}(\hat{r}_{ij};\widetilde{Ω}_i ,\widetilde{Ω}_j )=
  \begin{cases}
    1, & \text{if } \begin{cases*} \hat{e}_{α} · \hat{r}_{ij} \leq \cos(δ) & for some patch $ α$ on $ i $ \\[-0.6ex]
    & \llap{and}\\[-0.6ex]
    \hat{e}_{β} · \hat{r}_{ji} \leq \cos(δ) & for some patch $ β$ on $ j $
    \end{cases*} \\[4ex]
    0 & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is the perfect solution :) And yeah, using maths as text is probably not a very smart idea.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than embedding a second cases environment inside the first, I typeset equations like this by leaving a "blank" entry in left hand position on the next line. Doing this with your MWE gives the following:

[image]

Two other comments. You are using `\text{cos}` for the cosine function whereas TeX provides `\cos`, which is both easier to type and produces better results. Secondly, I like using the `cases*` environment from the [mathtools](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package because then the material on the right hand side of the cases environment is assumed to be text, so you don't need to use `\text{...}` everywhere.

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
f_{ij}(\hat{r}_{ij};\tilde{\Omega}_i ,\tilde{\Omega}_j )=
    \begin{cases*}
    1, & if $(\hat{e}_{\alpha}\cdot\hat{r}_{ij}\leq\cos(\delta))$ for some patch $\alpha$ on $i$ \\
       & and $(\hat{e}_{\beta}\cdot\hat{r}_{ji}\leq\cos(\delta))$ for some patch $\beta$ on $j$,\\
    0, & otherwise.
    \end{cases*}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I also fixed up the punctuation:) I also think that it improves readability if you drop the brackets and just write `\hat{e}_{\alpha}\cdot\hat{r}_{ij}\leq\cos(\delta)`, but this is probably a personal choice.

Comment: Also a good solution, but i personal think the equation looks better with the upper method.